# Accessing the dom outside ng-app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

Say I have an angularJS application, where I want to modify the dom. It makes sense that one should not do it via a service or a controller. Instead use a directive for DOM manipulations. But what should one do if the dom lies out of the scope of the angular app?

For Example:
Say I want to access the BODY tag and disable the scroll bars on it. I can't write a directive because `ng-app` directive is on a `div` which is deep inside the dom and thus the BODY tag is not accessible.

How does one tackle this problem? I read this [blog](http://joelhooks.com/blog/2014/02/11/lets-make-full-ass-angularjs-directives/), and it seems like it ok to do dom manipulations via a service. So what is really the best practice to access doms? Especially if its out of the scope of an angularjs app?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand without seeing your code.  But in general, the ng-app should be at the highest tag that encompasses all the functionality you want to manipulate with angular.  For most, that is the `body` tag itself.